# Unable to start the daemon process. problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon. For example, an unrecognized jvm option is use

Tags: android, flutter, jvm, daemon

When i run my project my .gradle folder is not been created and i get this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Unable to start the daemon process.
  This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
  For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
  Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
  Process command line: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe -Xmx1536M -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\IT CREATIVE PLUS.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.7-all\cuy9mc7upwgwgeb72wkcrupxe\gradle-6.7\lib\gradle-launcher-6.7.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.7
  Please read the following process output to find out more:

---

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind
- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind
  at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:61)
  at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:41)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.FileLockCommunicator.(FileLockCommunicator.java:51)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.getCommunicator(DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.java:263)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.reservePort(DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.java:255)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:108)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:95)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:90)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.OnDemandFileAccess.updateFile(OnDemandFileAccess.java:51)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.SimpleStateCache.update(SimpleStateCache.java:87)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator$1.create(FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.java:50)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.doUpdate(FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.java:67)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.update(FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.java:47)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry.store(PersistentDaemonRegistry.java:232)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonRegistryUpdater.onStart(DaemonRegistryUpdater.java:80)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon.start(Daemon.java:171)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonMain.doAction(DaemonMain.java:125)
  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:50)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon.main(GradleDaemon.java:22)
  Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind
  at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
  at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:84)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:93)
  at java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(DatagramSocket.java:392)
  at java.net.DatagramSocket.(DatagramSocket.java:242)
  at java.net.DatagramSocket.(DatagramSocket.java:299)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.FileLockCommunicator.(FileLockCommunicator.java:49)
  ... 22 more
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this daemon error in recent update of flutter. To fix this ,try re-installing flutter sdk.

Comment: I tried re-installing flutter sdk but its still not working